# Using simplehtmldom in PHP how do I get the data-href attribute?

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I am using this PHP library to work with a dom :http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

I am wanting to access the data-href element of a li element on this page:http://www.spareroom.co.uk/flatshare/bristol/

according to the api reference:
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm

This code should work - so long as $res represents the li dom node - which in my case it does:

```
echo $res->data-href;
```

However when i run that the echo is "0".... when I would expect to see something like :

```
"/flatshare/fad_click.pl?fad_id=3248085&search_id=&offset=0&city_id=&flatshare_type=offered&search_results=%2Fflatshare%2Fbristol%2F&"
```

Can somebody please help me to understand what I am doing wrong

Comment: You will need to quote data-href or just get any of the normal hrefs in <div class="listing_row listing_row3">

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$res->data-href` is parse as

```
$res->data - href
```

i.e. it's a subtraction, because `-` is not a valid character in an identifier. Try:

```
$res->{"data-href"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are accessing a object keys with special characters have to be quoted and surrounded with {}.
So:

```
echo $res->data-herf
```

Should be:

```
echo $res->{"data-href"}
```

In all honesty though it probably just easier(and safer) to use the method:

```
$res->getAttribute("data-href");
```